# GUID number of windows interface giving error: ValueError: Unknown network interface '{1619EEF1-4D71-4831-87AC-8E5DC3AA516A}'

Tags: python, scapy

Import scapy version 2.4.0. I am only using version 2.4.0 for my project

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import sys
```

by using IP address this function return related MAC address of the target

```
 def get_mac(ip):
   arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
   broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
   arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
   answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
   return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc

 def sniff(interface):
   scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)
```

This function checks whether default gateway MAC address is equal to my PC's MAC address table. if not it says "[+] You are under attack!!

```
 def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(scapy.ARP) and packet[scapy.ARP].op == 2:
       count = 1
       try:
          real_mac = get_mac(packet[scapy.ARP].psrc)
          response_mac = packet[scapy.ARP].hwsrc

          if real_mac != response_mac:
              count = count+1
              print(str(count) + "[+] You are under attack!!")
              sys.stdout.flush()
      except IndexError:
          pass
```

in Linux, we can use a value like 'etho' but In windows, I have to use GUID value to get the result. I am running this code in Windows Machine.

```
sniff('{1619EEF1-4D71-4831-87AC-8E5DC3AA516A}')
```

But this code return error

This is the Error that got raised

```
 raise ValueError("Unknown network interface %r" % name)
 ValueError: Unknown network interface '{1619EEF1-4D71-4831-87AC- 
 8E5DC3AA516A}'
```

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you need to provide a complete interface name / object, to be able to sniff on it.

First, have a look at what is available using `IFACES.show()` in a Scapy shell.

Then to get the interface, you can either use:

- `iface = IFACES.dev_from_name("...")` (or `dev_from_pcapname`, `dev_from_id`... have a look at help(IFACES) to see what’s available)
- iface = "the full name as printed above"

Then use it via `sniff(iface=iface)`.

You could provide the pcap_name, but not the GUID: for instance, it would be something like `\\Device\\NPF_{...}` rather than just `{...}`.

Also, please use scapy 2.4.3rc1 (or at least 2.4.2) to be sure you’re up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

I solved the `scapy` error  `ValueError: Unknown network interface` on `windows` by installing [npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/)

Comment: Yes, you need either WinPcap or Npcap to run libpcap-based software on Windows.