# Python error ValueError: Unknown network interface None

Tags: python, scapy, python-netifaces

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import requests
import json
```

This code work with API for getting information about venders

```
def vender_finding(mac_adr):
   mac_url = 'http://macvendors.co/api/%s'
   vender = (requests.get(mac_url % mac_adr))
   response_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(vender.json()))
   return response_dict['result']['company']
```

This code returns all devices connected to the network. result is something like this

[the result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQjuf.png)

```
def scan(ip):
   arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
   broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
   arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
```

This is the line which gives an error

```
   answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]

   clents_list = []
   for element in answered_list[1:]:
      company = vender_finding(element[1].hwsrc)
      clent_dict = {"ip": element[1].psrc, "mac": element[1].hwsrc, "vender": company}
      clents_list.append(clent_dict)
      print(clents_list)
   return clents_list


 scan('192.168.1.0/24')
```

but now its return error like this.
In here now a new error starts to occur.

```
answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
```

This the error that I am getting.

```
raise ValueError("Unknown network interface %r" % name)
ValueError: Unknown network interface None
```

Comment: Could you provide your plateform/OS/Python version/scapy version ? Also the value of `scapy.conf.iface` ? That would help figuring out what the problem is :)

Comment: scapy 2.4.0. with npcap, windows 8.1 and python 3.7.2

Comment: print(scapy.conf.iface) result = None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing the following software issue solved.

1.python 2.7.2 from python.org

2.Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266.

(check this link for more. [Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645519/microsoft-visual-c-9-0-is-required))

3.pip install scapy==2.4.3rc1 (this is recommended by StackOverflow contributor. this work very well.)

(check these link answer for a recommendation by user Cukic0d. [GUID number of windows interface giving error: ValueError: Unknown network interface '{1619EEF1-4D71-4831-87AC-8E5DC3AA516A}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075228/guid-number-of-windows-interface-giving-error-valueerror-unknown-network-inter))

4.winpcap (to perform scapy sniff() must install this)

Install python 2.7.2 and then install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can try "iface" with your network interface.
Ex:

```
sendp(Ether()/IP(dst="1.2.3.4",ttl=(1,4)), iface="eth1")
```

More info: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html